# Strange behavior of AEM Dispatcher:

Tags: aem, sling, requestdispatcher

We are using AEM 6.2 with Dispatcher 4.2 and ***after each page refresh the cache is not considered for response***.

There are Secure content which are secured by `/auth_checker` and cached by `/allowAuthorized`.
The URL of content is as follows,

https://www.securedcontent.com/content/sample.html

On load of above page, it requests via Ajax following request.
https://www.securedcontent.com/content/sample/some.query.json/sample/input.json

Both above URL result gets cached by dispatcher.

But if the page is refreshed (sample.html), only page html (sample.html) will be fetched from cache. input.json will not be fetched from cache but from publish server.

This is consistent and can be reproduced with another Ajax call to another URL like following.
https://www.securedcontent.com/content/sample/some.query.json/sample/another/input.json

But subsequent request to (input.json) would fetch from cache, until the page (sample.html) is refreshed.

**Details of our setup is as follows:**

Dispatcher configuration:

```
/aemsecuredcontent
{
    /auth_checker
    {
        /url "/bin/permissioncheck"

        /filter
        {
            /0000
            {
                /glob "*"
                /type "deny"
            }
            /0001
            {
                /glob "/content/securedcontent/*"
                /type "allow"
            }
        }
        /headers
        {
            /0000
            {
                /glob "*"
                /type "deny"
            }
            /0001
            {
                /glob "Set-Cookie:*"
                /type "allow"
            }
        }
    }

    /clientheaders{ "*" }

    /filter
    {
        /2401 { /type "deny"  /glob "*" }
        /2417 { /type "allow" /glob "*query.json*" }
    }

    /cache
    {
        /statfileslevel "1"
        /allowAuthorized "1"

        /rules
        {
            /0000
            {
                /type "allow" /glob "*"
            }
            /0001
            {
               /glob "*.nocache.html*"
               /type "deny"
            }
        }

        /invalidate
        {
            /0000
            {
              /glob "*"
              /type "deny"
            }
            /0001
            {
                /glob "*.html"
                /type "allow"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Request Header of URLs:**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: WT_FPC=id=39823rjfngfeihe9jwe; JSESSIONID=sjerht93qu4fg; login-token=48039qi4ig4joacrx.default
Host: www.securedcontent.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://www.securedcontent.com/content/sample.query.json/sample/input.json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

**Response Header of URLs:**

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 8303
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 24 May 2018 06:53:12 GMT
Expires: Sat, 23 Jun 2018 06:53:12 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Proxy-Server: something-proxywcm
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

**Dispatcher Log after every page refresh (not from cache):**

```
[D] [pid 23365 (tid 139886375950080)] checking [/cache-dir/content/sample.query.json/sample/input.json]
[D] [pid 23365 (tid 139886375950080)] cachefile does not exist: /cache-dir/content/sample.query.json/sample/input.json
[D] [pid 23365 (tid 139886375950080)] try to create new cachefile: /cache-dir/content/sample.query.json/sample/input.json
[D] [pid 23365 (tid 139886375950080)] cache-action for [/cache-dir/content/sample.query.json/sample/input.json]: CREATE
```

**Dispatcher Log of second Ajax request of the same URL (cached response):**

```
[D] [pid 23365 (tid 139886302521088)] checking [/cache-dir/content/sample.query.json/sample/input.json]
[D] [pid 23365 (tid 139886302521088)] Authorization checker: connected to backend rend01
[D] [pid 23365 (tid 139886302521088)] cache-action for [/cache-dir/content/sample.query.json/sample/input.json]
 [I] [pid 23365 (tid 139886302521088)] "GET /cache-dir/content/sample.query.json/sample/input.json" - -
```

Comment: not sure if I got your question correct, but I think you have set `statfileslevel "1"` which makes everything under /content/sample  expire when the page is activated.

Comment: In this case page is not getting activated.  

With just page refresh, Ajax call on that page are not getting from cache for the first time.  

Second time Ajax call, without refreshing the page, is fetching from cache.

Comment: It seems to me that the configuration is working fine, note that there is no CREATE when using the cached response. Please try the following to make sure if the publish indeed is serving the JSON every time. Go to the publish access logs, perform the Ajax requests, and confirm if the request is logged.

Comment: How is the second successful XHR issued that makes it different from the first? And how is the `Referer` in the request headers a `.json` url?

Comment: The second request is no different than first one, in terms of request headers and referer. It is just second time call to that URL (input.json), after page refresh.